# Knight movement.... " how to output all possible moves. "

Tags: c++

The following is the code i wrote.. I have to write it for nXn but for easyness i tried to test it for 5X5. It does not display my output... could anybody tell me whats wrong with the following code:

```
{ 
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void knight ( int startx, int starty, int n, int p[][5], int used [][5], int &count);

int main ( )
{
    const int n = 5; // no. of cloumns and rows
    int startx = 0;
    int starty = 0;
    int p[5][5];
    int used[5][5];
    int count = 1;

    int i= 0;
    int j = 0;

    //initializing the array
    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            p[i][j] = 0;
            used [i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    //outputting the initialized array.. 
        i=0;
        while ( i< 5)
        {
            for ( j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                cout << setw(3) << p[i][j];             
            }
            i++;
            cout << endl;
        }
        knight (startx,starty,n,p,used,count);

    return 0;
}

void knight ( int x, int y, int n, int p[][5], int used [][5], int &count)
{

        int i = 0;

    //knight (x,y,n,p,used,count)
    for ( i = 0; i < n*n; i++)
    {
        if ( used [x][y] == 0 )
        {
            used[x][y] = 1; // mark it used;
            p[x][y] += count; //inserting step no. into the solution

            //go for the next possible steps;

            //move 1
            //2 squares up and 1 to the left
            if (x-1 < 0 && y+2 < n && p[x-1][y+2] == 0)
            {   
                used[x-1][y+2] = 1;
                p[x-1][y+2] += count;
                knight (x-1,y+2,n,p,used,count);
                used[x-1][y+2] = 0;
            }

            //move 2
            //2 squares up and 1 to the right
            if ( x+1 < n && y+2 < n && p[x+1][y+2] == 0 )
            {
                used[x+1][y+2] = 1;
                p[x+1][y+2] += count;
                knight (x+1,y+2,n,p,used,count);
                used[x+1][y+2] = 0;
            }

            //move 3
            //1 square up and 2 to the right
            if ( x+2 < n && y+1 < n && p[x+2][y+1] == 0 )
            {
                used[x+2][y+1] = 1;
                p[x+2][y+1] += count;
                knight (x+2,y+1,n,p,used,count);
                used[x+2][y+1] = 0;
            }

            //move 4
            //1 square down and 2 to the right
            if ( x+2 < n && y-1 < n && p[x+2][y-1] == 0 )
            {
                used[x+2][y-1] = 1;
                p[x+2][y-1] += count;
                knight (x+2,y-1,n,p,used,count);
                used[x+2][y-1] = 0;
            }

            //move 5
            //2 squares down and 1 to the right
            if ( x+1 < n && y-2 < n && p[x+1][y-2] == 0 )
            {
                used[x+1][y-2] = 1;
                p[x+1][y-2] += count;
                knight (x+1,y-2,n,p,used,count);
                used[x+1][y-2] = 0;
            }

            //move 6
            //2 squares down and 1 to the left
            if ( x-1 < n && y-2 < n && p[x-1][y-2] == 0 )
            {
                used[x-1][y-2] = 1;
                p[x-1][y-2] += count;
                knight (x-1,y-2,n,p,used,count);
                used[x-1][y-2] = 0;
            }

            //move 7
            //1 square down and 2 to the left
            if ( x-2 < n && y-1 < n && p[x-2][y-1] == 0 )
            {
                used[x-2][y-1] = 1;
                p[x-2][y-1] += count;
                knight (x-2,y-1,n,p,used,count);
                used[x-2][y-1] = 0;
            }

            //move 8
            //one square up and 2 to the left
            if ( x-2 < n && y+1< n && p[x-2][y+1] == 0 )
            {
                used[x-2][y+1] = 1;
                p[x-2][y+1] += count;
                knight (x-2,y+1,n,p,used,count);
                used[x-2][y+1] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( x == n-1 && y == n-1)
    {
        while ( i != n)
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                cout << setw(3) << p[i][j];
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Is this for a school assignment?

Comment: http://debug-my-code.com

Answer (score 1):

First off, some compilers are picky and will give you a warning if the variable names are different in your function declarations and definitions.

```
void knight ( int startx, int starty, int n, int p[][5], int used [][5], int &count);
[...]
void knight ( int x, int y, int n, int p[][5], int used [][5], int &count) { ... }
```

Second, if you are trying to pass an `int` pointer into knight (parameter `count`) then you would use `int *count`. If you're going to be using recursion in `knight`, you might be better off either declaring `count` as a global, or (as it looks like here) if the count parameter is only valid for that particular call tree, you may want to not use a pointer, and just give each call its own `count`.

Third, what is with the rogue `{` at the top of the file? Did you mean to put that there?

What does the program do when you run it? Have you tried inserting debugging messages that print out in various parts of the code so that you can see where errors or infinite loops occur?

Comment: about your first concern, i have done that before and had no difference. i had worked well. So i don't think that is the problem. 
About the count:
Well lets say in 5X5 board, starting at (0,0), the code should display 304 solutions and, it should display all 304 5X5 boards with step no. on it.  like:
1  8  19 14 23
18 13  22 9 20
5   2  7 24 15
12  17 4 21 10
3   6 11 16 25 

.
.
.

so on ....
our starting position is always same but it will take different route with each iteration... 

so any ideas, what went wrong in my code?

I am not sure about "{". what is it you talking about?
Thank you

Comment: You forgot to answer the most important part of the question: *What does the program do when you run it?*

Comment: it only outputs the array 5 by 5.. all zeroes, which i set just to check if output is in correct format... and it is..  but it does not display any values for the steps of the knight move.

Answer (score 1):

These are all hints at different problems in your code:

At the point of your program where `if ( x == n-1 && y == n-1)` executes, what value does `i` have? How does it get that value?

What effect does this loop `for ( i = 0; i < n*n; i++)` *actually* have?

When you have an expression like `y-2 < n` is that really what you want? Can `y-2` ever *not* be less than `n`?

Comment: what i am thinking here is that the value of x increases as well as y with every recursive call in the function. Did it not work that way? And i is just a loop variable, just trying to have n times n iterations.  What am i doing wrong???? 

The program should find each and every possible solutions for the knight move. For example, starting at 0,0 we should get 304 solution and all the solutions should be outputted in 5X5 board format, 304 of them.. 

So any idea where i went wrong..
thank you

Comment: Don't just assume that you know what value `i` will have. Find out and let us know.

Answer (score 1):

i got the answer using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

bool move(int *p[] ,int x, int y,int n);
void knights (int *p[],int x,int y,int n, int count, int &pmt);
void output(int *p[],int n);

int main(char argc, char *argv[])
{

    int count = 1;
    int pmt = 0;
    int n;  //for size of board
    int x,y; // starting pos
    int **p; // to hold no. of combinations

    if ( argc != 4)
    {
        cout << "Very few arguments. Please try again.";
        cout << endl;
            return 0;
    }

    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    if( argv[1] <= 0 )
    {
        cout << " Invalid board size. ";
        return 0;
    }

    x = atoi(argv[2]);
    y = atoi(argv[3]);

    cout << "board size: " << n << ", "<< n << endl;
    cout << "starting pos: " << x << ", " << y << endl;


    //dynamic allocation of arrays to hold permutation
    p = new int *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        p[i] = new int [n];    

    //initializing board
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            p[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    output(p,n); // check output format
    knights(p,x,y,n,count,pmt);
    cout << "no. perm " << pmt << endl;


    return 0;
}

void output(int *p[],int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j;

    while ( i != n)
    {
        for ( j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(10) << p[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
        i++;
    }
}

bool move(int *p[],int x, int y,int n)
{

    if (x < 0 || x >= n)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if ( y < 0 || y >= n)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if( p[x][y] != 0 )
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void knights (int *p[], int x,int y,int n ,int count , int &pmt)
{    
    if(!move(p,x,y,n))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (count == n*n)    
    {
        cout << "New solution found: " << endl <<endl;
        p[x][y]=count;
        output(p,n);
        p[x][y]= 0;
        pmt++;
    }

    if ( p[x][y] == 0 )
    {
        p[x][y] = count;

        //move 1
        knights (p,  x-1, y-2, n, count+1, pmt);

        //move 2
        knights (p,  x+1, y-2, n, count+1, pmt);

        //move 3
        knights (p,  x+2, y-1, n, count+1, pmt);

        //move 4
        knights (p,  x+2, y+1, n, count+1, pmt);

        //move 5
        knights (p,  x+1, y+2, n, count+1, pmt);

        //move 6
        knights (p,  x-1, y+2, n, count+1, pmt);

        //move 7
        knights (p,  x-2, y+1, n, count+1, pmt);

        //move 8
        knights (p,  x-2, y-1, n, count+1, pmt);

        p[x][y] = 0; //setting square back to zero
    }        
}
```

Comment: There's a rule of thumb I use: three or more, use a for! In your code, you've got eight calls to the `knights` function. You could put this inside a for loop and use the for loop indexer to look up offset values in an array. So you'd have `for (i=0 to 7) knights (p, x+xoff[i], y+yoff[i], n, count+1, pmt)`.